# When switching to GLSL 300, met the following error

Tags: glsl, glsles, opengl-es-3.0

when I switch to use OpenGL ES 3 with GLSL 300, I met the following error in my frag shader

undeclared identifier gl_FragColor

when using GLSL 100, everything is fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Modern versions of GLSL do fragment shader outputs simply by declaring them as `out` values,  and `gl_FragColor` is no longer supported, hence your error. Try this:

```
out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Note that `gl_FragDepth` hasn't changed and is still available.

For more information see https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader

Comment: How do I tell OpenGL that `fragColor` is the output variable? What if I have multiple outputs??

Comment: When using `GL_draw_buffers` the above would become `gl_FragData[0] = ...`, along with appropriate draw buffer setup/binding elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

The predefined variable `gl_FragColor` does not exist anymore in GLSL ES 3.00. You need to define your own `out` variable for the output of the fragment shader. You can use any name you want, for example:

```
out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    ...
    FragColor = ...;
}
```

This follows the Core Profile of full OpenGL. The reason for not having a pre-defined fragment shader output is that it does not scale well for multiple render targets, and for render targets that need types other than float vectors.